# How read collections of mongodb on django environment

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.x

I have this 2 collection on mongoDB

- [airports](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yAqCiMoR9JVuxWn69tgIyOe_nlIWDZou)
- [routes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tKxqXL_3G-MJGErAjJk9ML4ezmbUmqiy)

I was searching how do that, I found [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/). After reading I understood the following.
I must make  models that matching those data, then only use queries.
[image: examples of models]

There are models only with few fields. Then I could use this methods e.g.

```
Airports.objects.filter(name_airports__startswith='Goro')
```

am I right?

If anyone can guide me to right way , I'll be very grateful. If you have
an example on the web, please share that with us, thanks in advance.